# check if file exists without opening it with gf

Tags: file

`gf` edits the file whose name is under the cursor.

Sometimes I use `gf` to check if the file exist or not,
by just going to the file and coming back.
But if the file is large, then it takes time for opening it.

Is there a simple way in normal model to check the file whose name under the cursor
does exist or not?

Comment: `:h filereadable()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Maxim Kim hints in the comments, you can try

```
:echo filereadable(expand('<cfile>')) ? 'exists' : 'does not exist'
```

According to `:help <cfile>`, this should work exactly like `gf<C-o>` in terms of the filename used.

Comment: Could you show me a few examples `gf` can handle, but the method cannot?

Comment: I ended up with map like `nmap gG :echo filereadable(expand('<cfile>')) ? 'exists' : 'does not exist'<CR>`. Thank you.

Comment: @auditory use `nnoremap`. It turns out `<cfile>` does all the things `gf` does, so never mind about that!

Comment: okay. I will use non-recursive mappig like `:nnoremap ...`. Thanks.